# Error while open browser from selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my script

```
from selenium import webdriver
o = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and i get this problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1283, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

i searched on it and i found this 
[OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833589/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-selenium)

i get chromedriver and put it in '/usr/local/bin/'
like supposed,
it doesn't help
and also did the same thing with geckodriver 
[Trouble setting up selenium with python3(linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879974/trouble-setting-up-selenium-with-python3linux)

nothing work same error

and i try this shot

```
#!usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env bash
from selenium import webdriver 
web = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
```

it give me that error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    web = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Note : 
operation system is kali linux 
SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 version, 
firefox and selenium is up to date

Comment: Can you run geckodriver / chromedriver from the command line? Could it be that you're trying to run a windows executable on Linux, or an ELF executable on some Linux that doesn't support it, or something like that?

Comment: chromedriver work for me by command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver should be updated one & did u try webdriver.Firefox(driver_path) ?

Comment: i edit the question because your solution give me a error too

Comment: looks like your adding chrome driver path for Firefox module. add geckodriver for firefox. for more info visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: thanks man its work 
by version  geckodriver-v0.18.0-linux32.tar.gz
and the path to extract   geckdriver was  '\usr\local\bin'

Comment: Great News !!! Can you Accept the Answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer, just below vote Up/Down arrows, so the tick mark turns Green? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall instance of webdriver dependency and install the correct one which corresponds to your OS and browser version.Also when you give path of chrome ,it should end with chrome.exe and not chrome.

Comment: dear its linux there's no such thing like chrome.exe
and i did that read the question clearly